# Change ex-navigation bar title after component was mounted

Tags: react-native, navigation, ex-navigation

[Ex-navigation](https://github.com/exponent/ex-navigation) allows defining navigation bar title using static route

```
static route = {
  navigationBar: {
    title: 'title'
  }
}
```

I'd need to set navigationBar `title` programmatically after the component was mounted since it depends on data received from a server. How can I do it?

I've tried using `props.route.config`, but that only works when called in `componentDidMount()` but not later in component lifecycle.

```
this.props.route.config.navigationBar.title = 'new title'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `updateCurrentRouteParams` as described [here in the doc](https://github.com/exponent/ex-navigation#updating-route-params)
:

```
class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  static route = {
    navigationBar: {
      title(params) {
        return `Hello ${params.name}`;
      }
    }
  }

  callMeLatter() {
    this.props.navigator.updateCurrentRouteParams({name: "Jon Doe"})
  }
}
```

Comment: this.props.navigator.updateCurrentRouteParams undifiended